# Creating a Construction Tools Rectangle Template

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing, template, rectangle

I am working on a project that requires me to place hundreds of 20x20 ft squares as polygons in a feature class. Right now I am manually making them by entering height and width values. I am wondering if there's a way to create a template for a 20x20 ft square that I can place wherever I like. It would great if I could store this template in the construction tools window.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this in any particular program?

Comment: Many GIS programs allow you to select a feature, copy and paste it, then move the copy to the desired location. Perhaps this is possible in your software.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7

I have been copying and pasting - but even this gets  tiring when my nearest square is a few miles away.

Comment: You could create a fishnet using the create fishnet tool and then cut and paste polygons as needed. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-fishnet.htm

Comment: @GemmaLeigh You don't have to drag the copies; use the Edit/Move tool and specify +x miles east  or -x miles west, for example to get them near where you want them.